# An App to copy/move files from internal folder to sdcard? Temp Root?

Tags: android, root, android-sdcard

Is it possible to create an app that will copy image files from a internal memory location like /data without someone rooting their phone?

or somehow for the user to temporarily allow root access?

Will JAVA I/O work? is this the only way?

Comment: I am aware that an app that did something like this without a user intent would be scary. The intent of the app is to do something that can't be done without root permissions, and will clearly state so in the description. is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible without root because apps don't have filesystem permissions to read data directories of other apps. Temporary root needs [some exploit](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=803682) or unlock command to be executed which may be scary for users. What are you trying to copy?

Comment: I am try to copy/move image files from a internal memory location.